# how to capture the data that is outside of the join scope into a tempTBL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, temp-tables

Let's say we have the tables A and B, where A is the parent table of B

TableA:

```
ID | VAL
1  | "foo"
2  |  "bar"
```

TableB:

```
ID | aID
1  |  2
```

OK?

Now lets have an join:

```
select *
from A
inner join B on a.Id = b.aID
```

Is there a way to use the `INTO` keyword to immediately store the failed join record into a temporary table. Something similar using the OUTPUT clause?

I know that it is a bit far fetched, but maybe there is a way I'm not aware of. Pays off to try.

Comment: You can then use `FULL OUTER JOIN` query similar to yours with `WHERE a.Id IS NULL OR b.aID IS NULL` which you can `select * into #temp table`

Comment: I want to avoid doing an additional select query but do it in the same one since it's a huge query and pretty expensive. I need to process the data that got joined, but audit the records that are not in the join result

Comment: Why not `FULL OUTER JOIN` in `temp table 1` and then `SELECT into temp table 2 FROM temp table 1 WHERE a.Id IS NOT NULL AND b.aID IS NOT  NULL` and `SELECT into temp table 3 FROM temp table 1 WHERE a.Id IS NOT NULL AND b.aID IS NOT  NULL`. Or after putting `FULL OUTER JOIN` in `temp table 1` - `DELETE` all that you don't need with `OUTPUT deleted into temp table 3`

Comment: the issue is that it is about 420 000 000 records. But so far this is the most reasonable I found so far

Comment: Oh my... :0 that is a huge amount of records. Anyway - you need to get all of them.

Comment: If I can get all of it in one query, it would be an amazing time save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE ##tmp  (
    ID int,
    VAL nvarchar(3),
    IDD int,
    aID int
)

CREATE TABLE ##tmp1 (
    ID int,
    VAL nvarchar(3)
)

;WITH TableA AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
(1, 'foo'),(2, 'bar')) as t(ID, VAL)
), TableB AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
(1, 2)) as t(ID, aID)
)

INSERT INTO ##tmp
select  a.ID, 
        a.VAL,
        b.ID AS IDD,
        b.aID 
from TableA a
FULL OUTER JOIN TableB B on a.Id = b.aID

DELETE FROM ##tmp
OUTPUT deleted.ID, deleted.VAL INTO ##tmp1
WHERE IDD IS NULL
```

Data in `##tmp`:

```
ID          VAL  IDD         aID
----------- ---- ----------- -----------
2           bar  1           2

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Data in `##tmp1`:

```
ID          VAL
----------- ----
1           foo

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Please read the comments from before. I have about 420 000 000 records and you suggest that I store into Temps double the amount?

Comment: Well... It is an example. You can use `##tmp` instead of `@tmp`. I use 2 cte's because I don't have your tables. And that's me you talk in comments to your question :)

Comment: go ahead and edit the answer so I can remove the downVote

Comment: I don't understand what to edit? I gave an example of what we talk about in comments. :)

Comment: I downvoted you. I did not notice It was you. In order to remove the downvote, You need to edit it. ;)

Comment: I changed table variables to temporary tables in my answer :)

Comment: It did not help me, but in the case that someone does not have that crazy amount of data it will help him. Thank god the weekend is comming. It will be processing the whole weekend long :)

Comment: Hey! How is it going?

Answer (score 1):

Failed join record ? do you mean non matching records ?

```
select *
from A
left join B on a.Id = b.ID 
where b.ID IS NULL
```

To store in temporary table , create table structure with required columns from rows retrived in join operation then do

```
INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT * from A
left join B on a.Id = b.ID 
where b.ID IS NULL
```

or if you require all the columns then do `select * into`

```
SELECT * INTO #temp from A
left join B on a.Id = b.ID 
where b.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: I'm not asking about how to make an outer join, but how to have the outer join result stored into a temp table in the same select statement and avoid doing a separate query with an outer join.
It is possible to save the results of an update into a temp table but

Comment: last query is doing the join operation and insert into table at same time , no need to write separate query

Comment: I am storing the successful join data into a tempTable, but I need to store the failed data into somewhere else

Comment: the IS NULL condition is checking for unsuccessfull i.e. non matching records

Comment: I know. But I am looking for a way to immediately store both. joined and unjoined records